# Starting/Stopping sound with javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, onclick

this is my first post and I have searched a bit for an answer, but haven't come across any solutions.

Basically all I want to do is make onClick="" both start and stop audio with the javascript function, playSound(sound). Here is what I've ended with so far. Right now, no audio plays when I click, but when I test the single code 'song1.play()' by itself the sound plays, but obviously doesn't stop when clicked again. Hopefully this isn't too difficult.

```
function playSound(sound){
        var song1=document.getElementById(sound);
        var isPlaying = true;
        if (!isPlaying){
            isPlaying == true;
            song1.play();
        } 
        else{
            isPlaying == false;
            song1.pause();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two small corrections.

a) `var isPlaying = true;` should be declared globally to retain its values between multiple calls to "OnClick".

b) The `==` should be changed to `=` in assignment statements of `isPlaying' variable.

```
var isPlaying = true;
 function playSound(sound){
            var song1=document.getElementById(sound);
            if (!isPlaying){
                isPlaying = true;
                song1.play();
            } 
            else{
                isPlaying = false;
                song1.pause();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were comparing the isPlaying variable with true and false, instead of assigning them to the variable. This should work now.

```
function playSound(sound){
    var song1=document.getElementById(sound);
    var isPlaying = true;
    if (!isPlaying){
        isPlaying = true;
        song1.play();
    } 
    else{
        isPlaying = false;
        song1.pause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use =  instead of ==

> = is Assignment operator where as == is comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a sound is paused using the `paused` property:

```js
function playSound(sound) {
  var song1 = document.getElementById(sound);
  song1.volume = .25; // setting the volume to 25% because the sound is loud
  if (song1.paused) {  // if song1 is paused
    song1.play();
  } else {
    song1.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<audio id="sound">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<button onclick="playSound('sound')">Play/Pause</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It turns out doing scripts within html just makes some things not work. I put this in a seperate js file and linked it to the html and it worked perfectly, thanks.